# How to insert create-react-app project into existing python/flask app

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

We have an existing python/flask app (made by someone else) that has a nav bar, sidebar and different pages. We have built a create-react-app project that we want to sit on one of these pages in the python/flask app.
The question is - how can we integrate our react app into the existing python/flask codebase?
Any help gratefully received!

Update: from helpful answer below - could anyone help with explaining this a little more - perhaps with code examples? "render a container in the same template that react can mount on."

Update 2: Someone else suggested "You can have React run anywhere where you can add a script tag into HTML and a DOM element to attach it to. As long as you have a way to bundle and serve the JS files, you should just be able to include your new app like that." - could anybody help with code examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

A rough outline would be:

1. configure the build folder to be the folder where static files are served from by your server (`js`, `css`, ...)
2. include the files from that folder in the template of the page your want your react app to display (via `<link>` and `<script>` tags).
3. render a container in the same template that react can mount on.

Comment: Thank you- that sounds helpful, do you got any/seen any examples of this being done - example code?